# Mkey state activate via WinTitle?

Tags: lua, autohotkey, logitech-gaming-software

I’m using Logitech G13 & G510s, each device have M1-M2-M3 banks, and I want set auto activation each bank to specific WinTitle.

Solution**1**: I’m thinking of using AHK to monitor WinTitle, and send MKey state to LGS.
But I’m. It sure is it possible.

Solution**2**: use LGS script to monitor WinTitle - also, if it possible
Any ideas would be appreciated

I'm newbie to LGS scripting, so just starting discover it

Comment: LGS is unable to read window title.  LGS automatically switches to a profile for the program which is currently foreground.  LGS may have a separate profile for each exe file on your hard drive.  Each profile has its own Lua script.  In a Lua script you could set any MKey you like.  Does this solve your problem?

Comment: HI Egor! Thank you for reply. not yet. Do I understand correctly that SetMKeyState() cannot be changed using IsKeyLockOn? 
Whole idea is to set:
capslock - SetMkeyState M1 
scrollock - M2 
numlock - M3

Comment: What is your problem exactly?  Do you want MKey be set depending on the program running or depending on CapsLock/ScrollLock/NumLock LED?

Comment: I work in music software Cubase, which has 3 other windows, with WinTitle as:
1. Cubase Pro Project
2. Key Editor 
3. Sample Editor. 

I want G13 to automatically switch M1-M2-M3 banks when my focus is on one of these windows.  Right now I have couple of simple AHK scripts working this way. 
My goal is to achive, somehow LGS react in similiar way. 
Thank you so much for helping me figure this out.

Comment: If all 3 windows are created by the same exe file, LGS is unable to understand that the current window has switched to another one.  Do you have ability to edit Cubase settings to assign your keys for switching windows?  For example, can you set keyboard keys `A`,`B`,`C` to switch Cubase to window #1, #2 and #3 accordingly?

Comment: Yes, i can assight any combination, to each window. It also opened in separate window, when i doubleclick at audio event(clip). 
In my workflow, i'm using 3 monitors, where all 3 window already opened, i'm just switching mouse cursor between them.

Comment: Can you switch to existing window without creating it by pressing key `A`?  If yes, then you can press a mouse button (6,7,8), mouse press event handler in Lua will invoke `SetMKeyState(1/2/3)` to set M-key and `PressAndReleaseKey("A/B/C")` to switch Cubase to another window simultaneously.

Comment: Egor thank you! That’s interesting idea. Does LGS Lua accept F13-F24 keys? It more easy and safe,  assign it in cubase

Comment: Yes, `PressAndReleaseKey("f13")` should work.